# Working with user uploaded image in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I've built a model that can take in an image, read it at the pixel level, then decide if the image contains a cat or a dog. For educational purposes, I am now trying to put it into a Flask app (never used Flask before). What I have working so far: User uploads image, image is saved to disk by Flask, image is manipulated and sent to the model, model predicts and I generate an output page from a template. Now I'd like to display the image the user uploaded and I'm running into issues. The applicable code is here:

```
import flask
from flask import request, render_template
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from copy import deepcopy
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from PIL import Image
import catdog

# Initialize the app
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def viz_page():
    with open("frontend.html", 'r') as viz_file:
        return viz_file.read()

@app.route("/uploader", methods=["GET","POST"])
def get_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        sfname = 'images/'+str(secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(sfname)

        clf = catdog.classifier()
        #clf.save_image(f.filename)

        return render_template('result.html', pred = clf.predict(sfname), imgpath = sfname)


#--------- RUN WEB APP SERVER ------------#

# Start the app server on port 80
# (The default website port)
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

And the template:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Dog vs Cat</title>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h3> Prediction: {{ pred }} </h3>
      <br><br>
      <img src={{imgpath}}>
      <script>

      </script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

What I'm getting back out is the "Prediction: yada yada" part, which is working well. However, the image always comes back blank. When I look it's looking in `http://localhost:5000/images/cat.4.jpg` which I know means it's not looking in the right place, but I'm not sure how I can dynamically grab the image I want. I found this guide here: [How to pass uploaded image to template.html in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262518/how-to-pass-uploaded-image-to-template-html-in-flask) and I feel like that should be enough to help me, but I'm just not getting what the answers are trying to get me to see. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Bonus question: is it possible to never save the image and just constantly keep it in memory in Flask? Ideally, I'd never save the image, I'd just work with it, then toss it after a prediction was made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image should be saved in /static folder, so just change saving path to static/images

```
sfname = 'static/images/'+str(secure_filename(f.filename))
```

so than HTML template will be ready it will look like this

```
<img src="/static/images/your_image_here.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example of the shopping website,
We have the images for the particular product.

inside the model file

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
import os
from flask import url_for
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_admin import form
from jinja2 import Markup

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    product_description = db.Column(db.String(5000), nullable=False)
    product_price = db.Column(db.Float)
    category_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('category.id'),
        nullable=False)
    images = db.relationship('Image', backref='product', lazy=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_name)


class Image(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    path = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.product)


class ImageView(ModelView):
    """Creating a custom ModelView for the Image Model"""
    def _list_thumbnail(view, context, model, name):
        if not model.path:
            return ''

        return Markup(
            '<img src="%s">' %
            url_for('static',
                    filename=form.thumbgen_filename(model.path))
        )

    column_formatters = {
        'path': _list_thumbnail
    }

    form_extra_fields = {
        'path': form.ImageUploadField(
            'Image', base_path=file_path, thumbnail_size=(200, 100, True))
    }
```

And in your views goes like this

```
admin.add_view(ModelView(Product, db.session))
admin.add_view(ImageView(Image, db.session))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want to upload, analyze, and display the image **without saving it to storage**, i.e. api and edged image analysis. This example might be a guide for you, [Flaskimio](https://github.com/nonsakhoo/flaskimio) guides to process the uploaded image without saving them to storage, only use memory and base64 data parsing between the Python api and html display script.

```
@app.route("/",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            print('No file attached in request')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            print('No file selected')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and check_allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            print(filename)
            img = Image.open(file.stream)
            with BytesIO() as buf:
                img.save(buf, 'jpeg')
                image_bytes = buf.getvalue()
            encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode()         
        return render_template('index.html', img_data=encoded_string), 200
    else:
        return render_template('index.html', img_data=""), 200


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input type="file" id="file" name="file"><input type=submit value=Upload></p>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ img_data }}" id="img-upload" alt="img_data" class="img-upload"/>
</form>
```